# Is there a tutorial for Ghost Recon: Advanced Warfighter?

Tags: ghost-recon-advanced-warfighter

I have problems commanding my squad in Advanced Warfighter. It seems like I can't command them to follow me all the time. All I can issue them is something like "Come to me", but when I move again, they stay.

I have read the manual, but according to it, I'm doing everything alright (Press ^ to select entire squad, select "follow" and press ^ again).

It looks like I'm missing a tutorial how to command, how to move and such. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score -2):

Have you checked the following link, it is a 91 page guide to playing GRAW.

http://guides.gamepressure.com/ghostreconadvancedwarfighter/

Comment: Please include the relevant information from the link, so that this answer is still useful in the case of the link being broken.  Currently, your answer shows no effort, it looks like you googled "GRAW guide" and pasted the link.

Comment: -1 the link does not provide any info that is useful to the OP, apart from pages 1 - 4 the rest is a walkthrough, page 1 is just an front page and 2 - 4 just have hints and don't even address commanding the squad which the OP is asking about. as @turbo has said this is a copy and paste of a link from a Google search with no real research effort made to ensure accuracy of answer